# Drawing Issues - Drawing a compound shape from other shapes

Tags: java, drawing

So I have an assignment for University. The concept was that we were to complete some class hierarchy stuff. Basically it was stuff to allow us to draw different shapes.

I can successfully draw each shape; where I need it to be and how big I need it to be, like required... the part I'm having trouble on is this compound hierarchy.

Basically we're supposed to have a new class called `Compound.java` and extending from that we are supposed to have three other classes, `House`, `tree`, and `earth`; each of which are supposed to take the shape objects we created (Rectangle, Square, Line, Oval and Circle) and draw the required pictures as denoted by the class name.

Where I am having the problem is in the house class; for example: I can get it to draw one rectangle but when I try to get it to draw the second rectangle after, it basically forgets about the first and only draws the second!

We haven't had any practice with the Graphics stuff so I don't know any methods or anything that I can call to draw then continue in the `House` constructor.

I understand why it overwrites the first rectangle, when the `House` constructor is called, it runs through all the stuff in the constructor, then goes back up to the `Compound.java` and draws it using the `draw(Graphics g)` method....

But I don't know how to fix it! Any help would be appreciated... it's due tomorrow.

Here's all the code:

**Shape.java:**

```
import java.awt.*;

public abstract class Shape {
    int initX, initY;
    Color fillColour;

    public Shape() {
        initX = 0;
        initY = 0;
    }

    public Shape(int x, int y) {
        initX = x;
        initY = y;
    }

    public void setInitX (int x) {
        initX = x;
    }

    public void setInitY (int y) {
        initY = y;
    }

    public abstract void draw(Graphics g);
    public abstract double Area();
    public abstract double Perimeter();

    public void Move(int deltaX, int deltaY){
        //future work
    }

}
```

**ClosedShape.java :**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public abstract class ClosedShape extends Shape {
    boolean polygon;
    int numPoints;
    int[] xVertices;
    int[] yVertices;
    int x,y,width, height;

    public ClosedShape(boolean isPolygon, int numPoints) {
        super(0,0);
        this.polygon = isPolygon;
        this.numPoints = numPoints;
    }

    public ClosedShape(boolean isPolygon, int numPoints, int[] x, int[] y) {
        super(x[0],y[0]);
        this.polygon = isPolygon;
        if (isPolygon) {
            this.numPoints = numPoints;
            xVertices = new int[numPoints]; // error check?  if x.length == numPoints
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { // make copy of array: why?
                xVertices[i] = x[i];
            }
            yVertices = new int[numPoints]; // error check?  if y.length == numPoints
            for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) { // make copy of array
                    yVertices[i] = y[i];
            }
        }
        else { // its an oval - define bounding box
            this.numPoints = 4;
            this.x = x[0];
            this.y = y[0];
            width = x[1];
            height = y[1];
        }
    }

    public void setXYCoords(int[] x, int[] y){
        this.xVertices = x;
        this.yVertices = y;
    }

    // Gives access to the width attribute
    public void setWidth(int width){
        this.width = width;
    }

    // Gives access to the height attribute
    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        if (polygon) {
            g.drawPolygon(xVertices, yVertices, numPoints);
        }
        else {
            g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
        }

    }

    public abstract double Area();
    public abstract double Perimeter();








}
```

**Rectangle.java :**

```
public class Rectangle extends ClosedShape
{

    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        super(true, 4);

        setWidth(width);
        setHeight(height);

        int [] arrayX = new int[4];
        arrayX[0] = x;
        arrayX[1] = (x+width);
        arrayX[2] = (x+width);
        arrayX[3] = x;

        int [] arrayY = new int[4];
        arrayY[0] = y;
        arrayY[1] = y;
        arrayY[2] = y+height;
        arrayY[3] = y+height;

        setXYCoords(arrayX, arrayY);

    }

    public double Area()
    {
       return 0;
    }

    public double Perimeter()
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**Compound.java :**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class Compound
{
    boolean polygon;
    int[] xVertices;
    int[] yVertices;
    int initX, initY;
    Color fillColour;

    public void setXYCoords(int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        this.xVertices = x;
        this.yVertices = y;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        if (polygon) {
            g.drawPolygon(xVertices, yVertices, 4);
        }
        else {
            g.drawOval(1, 1, 1, 1);
        }

    }

}
```

**House.java :**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class House extends Compound
{

    public House(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {

        int [] arrayX = new int[4];
        arrayX[0] = x;
        arrayX[1] = (x+width);
        arrayX[2] = (x+width);
        arrayX[3] = x;

        int [] arrayY = new int[4];
        arrayY[0] = y;
        arrayY[1] = y;
        arrayY[2] = y+height;
        arrayY[3] = y+height;

        setXYCoords(arrayX, arrayY);
        this.polygon = true;

        Rectangle house = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

        int [] arrayXTwo = new int[4];
        arrayXTwo[0] = x+(width/4);
        arrayXTwo[1] = x+(2*(width/4));
        arrayXTwo[2] = x+(2*(width/4));
        arrayXTwo[3] = x+(width/4);

        int [] arrayYTwo = new int[4];
        arrayYTwo[0] = y+(height/4);
        arrayYTwo[1] = y+(height/4);
        arrayYTwo[2] = y+height;
        arrayYTwo[3] = y+height;

        setXYCoords(arrayXTwo, arrayYTwo);
        this.polygon = true;

        Rectangle door = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

    }


}
```

Comment: @Danny Beckett lol yeah sorry.... I've just been working on this for so long and I'm getting really irritated cause I can't find out what I'm doing wrong and cant seem to get help from anywhere...

Comment: I've edited your question so it's a bit easier to read... maybe you'll get some better luck!

Comment: How do the `Rectangle` of `house` and `door` get remember by the `House`.  First, they are defined locally, secondly, there doesn't seem to be any way for the `Compound` class to actually recognize them at all.  I would imagin the intention of the `Compound` class isn't to construct a `Ploygon` but to maintain a list of `Shape`s, which it would iterate through and `paint`.  Now the question I have, why are you reinventing the wheel?  `Shape` and `Rectangle` are already part of JavaSE

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well `House` is supposed to extend `Compound`... and `House` is supposed to draw 2 `Rectangle`s, 2 `Square`s and a `Triangle`...I'm not too terribly sure how I would go about making it draw the required shapes other than the way I have it set up...if I try to just call `Rectangle(a,b,c,d);` in `House` I get just a singe dot in the upper left corner... of correct colour but no matter what I change **a b c** or **d** to it just stays as a dot... and I know, it's just what my crazy teacher made us do... she once made us make a class to calculate the cos(x)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sample code, there is no way that to "add" any shapes to the `Compound` class.  From your description, `Compound` should be a "container" of shapes.  Something more along the lines of...

```
public class Compound
{
    private List<Shape> shapes;

    public Compound() {
        shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>(25);
    }

    public void addShape(Shape shape) {
        shapes.add(shape);
    }

    public Iterable<Shape> getShapes() {
        return shape;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        for (Shape shape : shapes) {
            shape.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to decide, where is it best to associate the `Color` with the `Shape` should it be defined for the shape itself?  That means you can't reuse the shape. Or with the `Compound` shape?